# Using the minted escapeinside option with the pycon lexer

Tags: minted, python, pygments

What's going on here?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

% I want to show the output as latex, this is a minimal repro without any output at all
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=QQ,python3=true]{pycon}
>>> g = str('e_x e_y e_z')
\end{minted}

% works fine otherwise
\begin{minted}[python3=true]{pycon}
>>> g = str('e_x e_y e_z')
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Why did the `g = str(` get removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `pygments` bug, and out of the control of `minted`: https://github.com/pygments/pygments/issues/1516.

Edit: PR to fix this here: https://github.com/pygments/pygments/pull/1517